# How to remove GIT? I want to push to my own repository

Tags: git, versioning

I have a project versioned with GIT, but I am unable to commit to the repository. How can I remove GIT? I mean: remove the GIT versioning from my project.

Comment: `rm -rf .git` in the root of your project, you can then `git init` again, or use a different VCS.

Comment: what is vcs?. i think i delete .gitmodules,how to repair it?

Comment: Hello, your edit changed your entire question, please never do that.

Comment: (In case anyone else was wondering: it was edited within the grace period. [This suggested edit is the only thing that shows the history now.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5378229))

Comment: sorry,i make a mistake,you are just answered the question too fast that i have no time to change to my real question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove, you should `rm -rf .git` and `rm .gitignore .gitmodules`

**VCS** is version control system, like git svn.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible. You’ll probably be fine just versioning the graphics; if they don’t change much, they won’t take up an excessive amount of space. Otherwise, you could write a script to fetch them separately from somewhere else after a checkout.